# product search across 3 database tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

I am trying to create a product search feature on an E-commerce website I am building but am having a little trouble.

I have 3 tables (categories, sub_categories, products)

Categories table fields: (categoryID, categoryName, active, image)

sub_categories table fields: (categoryID, categoryName, parentCatID, active, image)

products table fields: (productID, shortDescription, longDescription, image, catID, subCatID, active, price, delivery, weight)

Im trying to get my search to find a product if a user types in any part of the short description or long description or if the user types in any part of the category or sub category names it should find all products within those categories.

I dont know whether to do a JOIN or multiple SQL queries. to be honest i've been tinkering with it for a few hours but havnt really gotten anywhere and am now back at the drawing board asking for help

my first attempt looked like this:

```
 $catSelect = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryName LIKE '%{$term}%'"); 
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($catSelect);
 $subCatSelect = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sub_categories WHERE categoryName LIKE '%{$term}%' OR parentCatID = '%{$row1[0]}%'");
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($subcatSelect);
            $productSelect = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE short_description LIKE '%{$term}%' OR long_description LIKE '%{$term}%' OR subCatID = '%{$row2[0]}%' OR catID = '%{$row1[0]}%'");
```

my final attempt looks like this

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products  INNER JOIN categories ON products.catID = categories.categoryID WHERE categories.categoryName LIKE '%{$term}%'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Could someone help me with the SQL query I need to use?

Comment: your query attempts (even if wrong) would help everybody to understand your current skill level with SQL and propose a solution accordingly. Moreover, the more effort you show, the better answers you'll receive

Comment: ok, editing to accommodate your suggesetions (making radical use of the undo button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.productID
FROM
    products p
LEFT JOIN categories c
    ON c.categoryID = p.catID
LEFT JOIN sub_categories sc
    ON sc.categoryID = p.subCatID
WHERE
    p.shortDescription LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR p.longDescription LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR c.categoryName LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR sc.categoryName LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: I was just writing the exact statement out myself, you beat me too it. I got to the WHERE clause before your answer popped up! Anyway @Kevlar once you have this working, i suggest looking a mysql full text searches, they are a little more difficult to understand, but are a better alternative to the LIKE's when doing this kind of searching (i.e. faster and sort of ignore common words such as "The Beatles" and "Beatles" in a music artist search would be different with those LIKE's, but full-text would ignore "THE")

Comment: @Lee nice suggestion about `FULLTEXT` searches :)

Comment: I will certainly look into it..im a little pushed for time at the moment and my abilities mean I have to keep it simple for now

Comment: @Stephan I'm a little confused about what the p.productID is? where does the p come from? same for categories c and sub_categories sc

Comment: @Kevlar : its quite common that when you have multiple table names, you use table aliases. So rather than typing "products.column_name" everytime you want to specify a colum from the products table, you just use the alias of P. You can see in the FROM clause where it says `FROM products p` (i would normally write `FROM products AS p` but the "as" is optional). You can make aliases for tables, columns, databases e.c.t. For the most part, we use them because we are lazy and typing `p` many times is quicker than typing `products` (which is perfectly fine and legal), they do have non-lazy uses too

Comment: @Kevlar unfortunately Stackoverflows comment text limit, meant that i couldn't explain aliases as well as i would have liked, but if you need any further info on aliases, there's some basic column and table alias info available at w3schools here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @Lee or Stephen. just one question. I've got the query to work however...if I change the term searched for the results dont seem to change. It just keeps fetching the same products? I even just typed in "zzz" and it fetched all the same products...any idea what causes this?

Comment: @Stephan its a little hard to show the output its just a load of product information from the database...but that information isnt changing with different search terms...there is only 1 keyword (named $term) which is the search term..and the results coming back are the same no matter what that term is

Comment: @Kevlar hmm.. maybe the keywords used are present for the same list of products ... try searching by a long string like `wxcs312ssd23qd3d`

Comment: @Stephan tried that..tried searching for something that is never going to be in the database like "xxxyyyzzz" but it just brings back all the same products...it doesnt matter what i search for

Comment: @Stephan actually never mind I see my problem. I was missing a "$" before one of my usages of "$term" i've fixed that and it appears to be ok...thanks for all your help...your code was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a join, on all three tables, with a where clause that queries the fields you want to search. Something like this:

```
select * from 
products
inner join categories on products.catID = categories.categoryID
inner join sub_categories on products.subCatID = sub_categories.categoryID
where
products.shortDescription like '%query%'
or products.longDescription like '%query%'
or categories.categoryName like '%query%'
or sub_categories.categoryName like '%query%'
;
```

where the `query` is the search query string.

Answer (score 2):

this can be helpful to you.....

```
SELECT * FROM products AS  PT 
LEFT JOIN Categories AS CT ON CT.catID = PT.catID
LEFT JOIN sub_categories  AS SCT ON SCT.subCatID = PT.subCatID
WHERE 
  PT.active = 'YES' AND 
  (PT.shortDescription LIKE '%shortDescription%' OR 
   PT.longDescription LIKE '%longDescription%' OR 
   CT.category LIKE '%category%'  OR 
   SCT.categoryID LIKE '%sub category%' )
```

you just put your values using php varrible you can get your search results.

Comment: indentation, indentation, indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use lucene-solr for this?